# MacBook getting hot while playing games

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

I've got a 2019 quad-core Pro. Recently I installed playonmac so I could play a couple of old computer games I love (like Championship Manager 01/02). However, whenever I play it the fan goes on maximum and the temperature shoots up towards 90. I wouldn't have thought this would be particularly intensive, any thoughts?

Comment: I use wine to run halo2 and I haven’t seen the temperature but cpu usage goes up to 50% and fans start running. Just keep it ventilated and you’d be fine

Comment: First, I highly assume you are talking about a MacBook Pro 2019 with a quad-core CPU (therefore it must be a 13" model). Second, open the Activity Monitor to see which process is running